# Why drawVertices in android canvas need hardware acceleration disabled?

Tags: android, canvas, hardware-acceleration, vertices

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257100/3286489, in order for drawVertices to draw something in Android Canvas, it need to disable Hardware acceleration using

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I check the underlying code, it has this check

```
    public void drawVertices(@NonNull VertexMode mode, int vertexCount, @NonNull float[] verts,
            int vertOffset, @Nullable float[] texs, int texOffset, @Nullable int[] colors,
            int colorOffset, @Nullable short[] indices, int indexOffset, int indexCount,
            @NonNull Paint paint) {
        checkRange(verts.length, vertOffset, vertexCount);
        if (isHardwareAccelerated()) {
            return;
        }
        // ... codes that perform the drawing
   }
```

Why can't we use hardware acceleration on it?

It is not mentioned in the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawVertices(android.graphics.Canvas.VertexMode,%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20short[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Comment: `drawVertices` is listed as unsupported here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#unsupported

Comment: Also if you are using `drawVertices()` you should probably be considering `TextureView`/`GLSurfaceView` and doing full OpenGL ES calls as `Canvas.VertexMode` matches OpenGL ES drawing modes.